# LWC lightning-card border not shown with slds-card_boundary

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

> Playground example
>   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/KLHs3GU9

I have a Lightning Web Component template with a `lightning-card` in an App Page.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="parent"></lightning-card>
</template>
```

I would like to nest more cards into it to simulate the related list look and feel from standard Lightning experience.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="parent">
        <lightning-card title="child></lightning-card>    
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

This renders the child without borders, filling the entire width of the parent.

If I add the `slds-card_boundary` class to the child, it draws a misplaced vertical border fragment above and below the card.

However, if I add the `slds-card_boundary` class to the `article` element spawned by the child `lightning-card` component, the border is correctly drawn around the entire card. Adding a `slds-m-around_small` to `article` element also forces a separation between parent and child cards.

What layout concepts am I missing with Lightning Web Components to be able to successfully use `lightning-card` components?

In general, how can `lightning-cards` be used inside Lightning Web Components to achieve a related list-like appearance?

Comment: You'll probably have to roll your own - I think it's how the shadow dom kind of interferes with nested child components and their styles.

Comment: I mean... there's not much to a card so you can just do this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/KLHs3GU9/3/edit

Comment: Sure, I can just write whatever the card spawns manually, starting from article onwards, but what’s the point in a component library if components do not work?

Comment: If I am getting this right, and that you need a related list experience as you see on desktop, you will need to utilize different `lightning-card` components here. [Is this how](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/AmawuaUl/1/edit) you expect this to be rendered?

Comment: @JayantDas That's very close, yes. `slds-card` seems wrong as it introduces additional padding, but other classes do bring it closer to the experience. Most importantly, is this sort of visual behaviour documented somewhere, or do I just go to standard interfaces and inspect to see what's going on?

Comment: If its only about styling, then you should take a look at the [SLDS classes](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/#About-Cards) that you can implement here. That will get you close to what you are looking for. But to answer to your question - yes you can utilize this component for what you are looking for.

Comment: Most of the components work, it's just nesting of components that is problematic in lwc... I don't think they've solved it yet in quite a few cases.

Answer (score 11):

I've run into the same issue. It appears the styling for `<lightning-card>` may be broken at this time with LWC. What you can do is simply add a class onto the card and give it a style of `display: block`.

So in your .html file:

```
<lightning-card title="parent" class="my-card"></lightning-card>
```

And in a .css file:

```
.my-card {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: this works for me! Thanks!

Comment: this solved my issue, thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my issue!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using Lightning Card to achieve this, use Lightning Layout Item & write a Div tag inside it.

Then apply this Class & CSS to it - `style:"border: 2px solid rgb(101, 153, 205);"` & `class="slds box"`.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem with a nested `lightning-card` and given that the markup is simple went for HTML with the appropriate classes added so I could place `slds-card_boundary` where it is needed:

```
<template for:each={tagsToResources} for:item="t">
    <div key={t.tags} class="slds-card slds-card_boundary slds-m-around_medium">
        <div class="slds-card__header">
            {t.tags}
        </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
            <div for:each={t.resources} for:item="r" key={r.id}>
                {r.name}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I guess this is a case where the component authors haven't allowed the markup the SLDS authors expect to be created.